# RxJs merge operator to get latest data and accumulate using scan operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on angular and RxJs. I have a component to display routes based on date and depo selection and a form in that child component to add route.
I have created a planner service which is injected in both the component. List Component subscribes to getLatestRoutesForDateDepo$ and form component saves new route. It works well when I select new date depo and add routes for the first time. Now problem is that when I change the date and depo scan filter aggregates the previous data as well and get array from list.
Below is the code.

```
export class RoutePlannerService {

  constructor(routeClient:RouteClient) { }

  private dateDepoSubject = new Subject<{date:Date,depo:DepoResource}>();
 initialize(date:Date,depo:DepoResource){
    this.dateDepoSubject.next({date,depo});
  }


  private getRoutesForDateDepo$ = this.dateDepoSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(schedule =>  this.routeClient.getRoutesByDateAndDepo(schedule.date,schedule.depo.id))
  );

 
  private addRouteSubject = new Subject<CreateRoute>();
  saveRoute(route:CreateRoute){
    this.addRouteSubject.next(route);
  }

  getLatestRoutesForDateDepo$ = merge(this.getRoutesForDateDepo$,
    this.addRouteSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      // Save the operation to the backend
      concatMap(action => this.sendHttpRequest(action))
    ))
.pipe(
      scan((routes: RouteResource[], route: RouteResource) => {
        debugger;
          return [...routes, route];
      })
    );

  private sendHttpRequest(route: CreateRoute): Observable<RouteResource> {
    return this.routeClient.post(route)
                      .pipe(
                        catchError(err => {
                          return EMPTY;
                        })
                        ));
  }
}
```

Route List

```
routes$ = this.routePlannerService.getLatestRoutesForDateDepo$;

search() {
 this.routePlannerService.initialize(new Date(this.date), this.depo)
}
```

Route Form

```
  save(route: RouteResource): void {
    this.routePlannerService.saveRoute(data);
  }
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could do a *simple* stackblitz that demonstrates this issue. (Not your entire app).  That would help us help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhppp1?file=src/app/route-list/route-list.component.html

search button should get the list from server and then add button should add new element to the list.
its working fine.. until I am making another search request... basically search should get my values for that date and when new values is added it should be added to the list. but the values seems to be accumulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the definition of `getLatestRoutesForDateDepo$`:

```js
getLatestRoutesForDateDepo$ = merge(
    this.getRoutesForDateDepo$,
    this.addRouteSubject
).pipe(
    scan((routes, route) => [...routes, route], [])
);
```

With this definition, ALL emissions of both sources are getting accumulated into an array using `scan`.

Since you want to reset whenever `getRoutesForDateDepo$` emits, you can nest your `merge` inside a `switchMap` like this:

```js
getLatestRoutesForDateDepo$ = this.getRoutesForDateDepo$.pipe(
    switchMap(routes => merge(
        of(routes),
        this.addRouteSubject
    ).pipe(
        scan((routes, route) => [...routes, route], [])
    )
);
```

Here, instead of including `getRoutesForDateDepo$` as a source of the `merge`, we use it to trigger `switchMap`, which returns an observable that merges the `getRoutesForDateDepo` emission along with all future emissions of `addRouteSubject` . Whenever `getRoutesForDateDepo$` emits, our `switchMap` will create a new inner observable, which effectively resets your `scan`.

Hopefully that makes sense, but here a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67385129?file=src/app/route-service.service.ts&devtoolsheight=45).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the stackblitz. It was helpful.

Try something like this in your app:

```
scan((routes: RouteResource[], route: RouteResource) => {
  if (Array.isArray(route)) {
    return route;
  }
  return [...routes, route];
})
```

If the second argument to the scan is an array, it returns the array. Otherwise it adds the emitted route to the array.

The updated stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eckbag

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: This is working like a charm. just out of curiosity... don't we can re-subscribe or clear old subscription once this.getRoutesForDateDepo$ emits data again.
i.e. when we search it should re-subscribe(or clear old subscription) and not accumulate old data....

Comment: Since this code uses the async pipe, there isn't a way to "unsubscribe" and "re-subscribe". But you could *switch* to a new Observable as @BizzyBob shows in his answer.